# Accessing Tomcat context.xml param

Tags: tomcat, configuration

I have some application configuration that vary according to the target environment (such as configuration file location).
Since this configurations vary according to the host, I do not want to embed them on the WAR file.

According to the "Context Parameters" section in http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/context.html, it seems to be a good idea to place such configuration on the Tomcat conf/context.xml file, like this:

```
<Context ...>
  ...
  <Parameter name="companyName" value="My Company, Incorporated"
     override="false"/>
  ...
</Context>
```

But the problem is how to retrieve them in my application?

I do not use a Servlet class to receive requests (it is a soap web service project).

I tried to create a context listener like the below:

```
    public class SystemPropertiesHelper implements
            javax.servlet.ServletContextListener {


        @Override
        public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {

            System.out.println("Started!");
            ServletContext context = event.getServletContext();

            Enumeration<String> params = context.getInitParameterNames();
            while (params.hasMoreElements()) {
              String param = (String) params.nextElement();
              String value = context.getInitParameter(param);
              System.out.println(param + " -> " + value);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {

        }
    }
```

I changed the application web.xml to declare this class as a listener.
However, it was not able to retrieve the parameters of the context.xml file.
On the other hand, properties declared on web.xml (see below) were nicely retrieved.

```
  <context-param>   
  <param-name>test</param-name>
  <param-value>value-test</param-value>
  </context-param>
```

Please, could anyone help me on figuring out how to retrieve such parameters?
Would it be possible without JNDI stuff?
Or is there any other place more suitable to place such configurations?

thank you so much,

Leonardo Leite

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this @Leonardo Leite ? Even after 8 years have passed since this question was asked, I've been searching for way longer than I'd care to admit and still this doesn't seem to be a simple thing to do. Feels like this should be a 5 minute job.

Comment: About using the suggested solution (context.xml) I cannot remember... but I know that nowadays to solve the problem (accessing env vars in a JavaEE environment), System.getenv("MY_ENV_VAR_NAME") is working (at least for Wildfly 17).

Comment: I've pretty much come to the same conclusion that OS Level Environment Variables are really the only practical option for modern ways of working. I've tried pretty much every single officially documented best practice way of doing things, and they just don't work in practice.

Comment: Ah, another option (working here for Wildfly 17). In the standalone.xml: <property name="ambiente" value="${env.AMBIENTE:local}" />. In the Java code: System.getProperty("ambiente").